# Best way to incorporate Phone Number verification in the authentication process for a MERN stack application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to incorporate Phone Number verification in the authentication process for a MERN stack application.

I was thinking to use a combination of https://www.twilio.com/ and http://www.passportjs.org/.

Is this a good choice or is there a simpler/better way! *If possible provide code examples :)*

Note: I need to use the same Auth backend for a React Native app AND a React js web app!

Answer (score 1):

Please following documentation. They have provided detailed procedure and code how to add two-factor authentication in Node.Js

https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/quickstart/two-factor-authentication-nodejs